# ASP.NET Session persistance on AWS EC2

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've tried to use Amazon Web Services EC2 to test my IIS/ASP.NET application I'm developing and I've got the login working but the ASP.NET Session doesn't seem to maintain on reload of a page or on moving to another page.

Page_Load code from my Login Form page (the session gets set correctly until I either move page or refresh the LoginForm page)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                    if(Page.IsPostBack)
                    {
                            NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;

                            string username = nvc["username"];
                            string password = nvc["password"];
                            Hydra.WebService1SoapClient client = new Hydra.WebService1SoapClient();

                            string sid = client.LoginSession(username, password);

                            if (sid != "Incorrect details")
                                    HttpContext.Current.Session["loggedin"] = true;
                            else
                                    HttpContext.Current.Session["loggedin"] = false;
                    }
            }
```

Below is from my display page to show the session data.

```
      <% if (HttpContext.Current.Session["loggedin"] == null || (bool)HttpContext.Current.Session["loggedin"] == false)
               { %>
            <a class="menu" href="register.php">Create Account</a>
            <% } else { %>
            <a class="menu" href="hd.php">Dashboard</a>&nbsp;<a class="menu" href="ticketlist.php">Tickets</a> <a class="menu" href="admin/index.php">Admin</a>
            <% } %>

            Value: <% Response.Write("" + HttpContext.Current.Session["loggedin"] + " <br /> SID? " + HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID);  %>
```

I've tested this on my local IIS system and it works correctly (the session is persistant).

My question then is:
Does something on AWS not like InProc session state storage or is there another reason for the problem?

Comment: Are you running multiple ec2 instances behind a load balancer? Or just one?

Comment: @E.J.Brennan no it's a single instance no load balancing, max iis workers set 1, iis  settings checked that session state is improc with 20 min timeout and these requests are within a minute.

Comment: If you are using InProc session state then just switch to Sql Database to persist session. Its more reliable and you don't have to worry about deployments killing session. Its also very easy to setup Sql Database backed ASP.NET session state.

Comment: It seems my issue is to do with SOAP calls to the same application causing it to do some funky stuff with the session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be nothing unique about it if you are running a single ec2 server; I do it all the time on AWS and it behaves exactly like a non-AWS server.

Is there any chance you are running on a micro-instance, pushing it to its limits, and it is constantly recycling - and thus losing its state?

Comment: I am using a t2 micro... It is possible that is what's happening although I disabled app pool recycling... I'll try it first chance I get in the morning and get back to you :)

Comment: While this seemed like a pearl of hope I've tested it and I have 400mb free RAM so I can't see it being there.
I added a global.asax and write out to a file for each event and it looks like it's running through all of the events for every page load. I don't know if that helps at all?

Comment: It seems my issue is to do with SOAP calls to the same application causing it to do some funky stuff with the session
When I comment out `Hydra.WebService1SoapClient client = new Hydra.WebService1SoapClient();` the sessions persist